# Help me understand this microscope point spread function

Tags: microscopy

I am working with a Nikon Eclipse widefield fluorescence microscope.  I have measured the point spread function using fluorescent beads according to the protocol by [Cole et al. 2011](http://www.nature.com/nprot/journal/v6/n12/full/nprot.2011.407.html).  My result, shown below, is highly asymmetric in the axial direction.

My understanding is that asymmetry like this indicates spherical aberration.  My problem is that I am not sure where this aberration might be coming from.  I repeated the measurement with other objectives, a second bead sample, and two other microscopes of the same model and got similar results.  This makes me wonder if (1) something is just wrong with my measurement approach, or (2) if this PSF is normal and I'm just misinterpreting it.  Any thoughts?

For a few other details, I mounted the beads on a #1.5 coverslip and used Prolong Diamond mounting medium (1.47 refractive index).  All of the objectives were air objectives (i.e., no oil immersion).

[image]